# Service layer validation - throw exceptions or have wrapper ServiceResponse type

Tags: n-tier-architecture, service-layer, application-design

This is a general, architecture question, not a request for code examples or particular code solutions.

In a multi-layered applications we have 2 major options of handlings service layer validations:

1. **Service layer throws exception which Presentation layer should catch and handle.**

**PRO** for this approach is lightweight service layer signature but on the other hand there is a potential overhead of exceptions being thrown all around the place and since exceptions themselves are not the cheapest options one might want to reconsider this option.

2. **Introduce ServiceResponse wrapper type**

The type might be something like (pseudo code):

```
class ServiceResponse{
    boolean IsOk;
    array ErrorMessages;
    object OkResponse;
}
```

This is also in line with REST Services (although question is not about them) where Http response message actually acts as a ServiceWrapper with its StatusCode and Content.

**What approach do you prefer in your service layers and why?**

Comment: I personally prefer Exceptions for service layers. Mainly because you have to catch and act on them. If you return an object, you have to check the status manually (and maybe forget it) whereas with exception you are forced to act.

Comment: yes, that's a very good case for exceptions and in my opinion, maybe a single good reason to go that way since they just can't be ignored. on the other hand, i don't know if 'forgetting something' is a good reason for determining implementation direction, be it one way or the other.

Comment: Thats true. However forgetting to check if the return is valid (mainly not null) will in most cases break you application (nullpointerexception) and therefore should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

If Iam understanding your question correctly, your service layer is a library of some sort that you inject or depend upon, in your UI layer. It's better to throw exceptions at this level. If you ever decide to **Physically separate ** the services layer and expose it via an API layer (REST). You can always catch those exceptions at API Layer and return http response with correct http code and exception message. So yeah stick to exceptions to start with.